# how to find whether the focus is on the particular web element

Tags: selenium-webdriver

how to find whether the focus is on the particular web element in the selenium webdriver?

HTML tag is

```
<input type="text" class="form-control searchInput resetOnBarcode ui-autocomplete-input" anchor="input" tab="tabCon_1" tabindex="1" dropable="true" dropping="false" layer="1" marker="1" down_layer_marker="1" right_navigate="true" placeholder="Patient" info="patient" block_shift_tab="true" data-bind="value: addPatName" id="pat" autocomplete="off">
```

Need to check whether this element has the focus when the page loads.

Answer (score 3):

There is a method called `activeElement()` in webdriver to check whether the element in question is the focussed element.

You can do something like

```
WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.id('pat'));
elem.equals(driver.switchTo().activeElement());
```

In Python,

```
return self.driver.find_element_by_id('pat') == self.driver.switchTo().active_element
```

Answer (score 0):

Current (3.14.1) Python selenium usage is `driver.switch_to.active_element`. No parentheses, they're both attributes.